# What is the meaning of 很搭?

Tags: vocabulary

I have never heard of this adjective...?

Also I checked on Baidu and it was less than helpful...

http://zhidao.baidu.com/link?url=RobUqePv2YKUWD1PXNi_ZHv9awWxDw4oSQoJQPtHo5st56o9ELMlOm2-CAExjxKrGNRrEbKem5soSudPG34cCPP3Pq5XaMHdQDBCO02Oc-W

Comment: as any dictionary will say 搭 is a verb for more information on 很＋动词结构 see e.g. http://www.docin.com/p-700907383.html

Comment: more briefly：＂汉语８００虚词用法词典＂很（副）表示程度相当高。常见的用法有：２。很＋动词／动词词组（１）我对他   很了解 ，我觉得他是一个诚实的人，绝不会欺骗你。２。我对学校的教学很满意，老师门都  很认真负责。３。老师对我们的学习和生活都  很关心。４。我很喜欢看中国的电视，特别是电视剧，我觉得  很有意思。５。我  很担心出交通事故  ，所以每次开车出门都提心吊胆的。６。我  很怕感冒 ，一感冒我就咳嗽得厉害。７。我  很羡慕他拿到了全额奖学金。８。我  很愿意跟中国同学来往，他们对我的帮助也很大。９。刚来的时候，我  很想家。１０。爸爸妈妈对我出国  很不放心。Distinct from 很搭 in above examples 动词／动词词组 consists of at least 2 字 （including object，see ６），很搭  seems of low usage frequency (abbreviation of  很搭配？  jukuu has ２examples， ２。这条领带和这件衬衫很搭配。３。她的手袋和她的衣服很搭配。none for 很配搭）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「很搭 」is shortened form of 「很合配搭」(very compatible)

「配搭」(v)  " to match; to accompany" ; (n)  combination ;  pairing

「合配搭」= compatible

Answer (score 5):

You can think of it as two words 很搭 but it generally means very compatible, suitable, a good match.

The 很 is used as an adverb. ex: 很帥, 很酷, 很好
The 搭 is used as slang for being compatible.
You can also change up the adverb and use **滿**搭

It's usually used for clothing, 你穿這件還滿搭的. This clothing matches you.